# How to make custom xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have tried to serialize data using `XmlSerializer`. I have found very a useful post: [XML Serializable Generic Dictionary](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

But in fact I need to put the result of serialization not in file but in a string variable, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using some `StreamWriter` which points to file you can use `StringWriter` class.

```
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (YourType));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, yourObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

XmlWriter.Create() function has one overload which takes StringBuilder, try using it.